# How to center a text below a multicolumn enviroment

Tags: tables, multicolumn

how can i fix my table? I would like to center the `\(\%\)` and the two `\(\msec\)`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!h]
\centering
\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{c|cc|cc|cc}
    \toprule
    \(J\) & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Sovraelongazione} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\shortstack{Tempo di \\ salita}} &  \multicolumn{2}{c}{\shortstack{Tempo di \\ assestamento}} \\
    \midrule
    \(Kg\cdot m^{2}\) & &\(\%\) & &\(msec\) & & \(msec\) \\
    \midrule
    & \(PI-diff_{\omega_{bv},J_{var}}\) & \(PI-diff_{\omega_{bv},J_{mid}}\) & \(PI-diff_{\omega_{bv},J_{var}}\) & \(PI-diff_{\omega_{bv},J_{mid}}\) & \(PI-diff_{\omega_{bv},J_{var}}\) & \(PI-diff_{\omega_{bv},J_{mid}}\)\\
    \midrule
    \(0.225\) &\(0\) &\(0\) & \(27\)&\(28\) & \(69\)&\(71\)\\
    \(1.390\) &\(0.3\) &\(0.3\) &\(29\) &\(29\) &\(72\) &\(72\)\\
    \(8.406\) & \(0.4\)&\(0.4\) & \(33\)&\(29\) & \(107\)&\(89\)\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Off-topic: If you use the line-drawing commands of the `booktabs` package to generate well-spaced horizontal rules, you shouldn't be using vertical rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to put the elements of the second row again in a `\multicolumn`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!h]
\centering
\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{c|cc|cc|cc}
    \toprule
    \(J\) & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Sovraelongazione} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\shortstack{Tempo di \\ salita}} &  \multicolumn{2}{c}{\shortstack{Tempo di \\ assestamento}} \\
    \midrule
    \(Kg\cdot m^{2}\) & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\(\%\)} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\(msec\)} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\(msec\)} \\
    \midrule
    & \(PI-diff_{\omega_{bv},J_{var}}\) & \(PI-diff_{\omega_{bv},J_{mid}}\) & \(PI-diff_{\omega_{bv},J_{var}}\) & \(PI-diff_{\omega_{bv},J_{mid}}\) & \(PI-diff_{\omega_{bv},J_{var}}\) & \(PI-diff_{\omega_{bv},J_{mid}}\)\\
    \midrule
    \(0.225\) &\(0\) &\(0\) & \(27\)&\(28\) & \(69\)&\(71\)\\
    \(1.390\) &\(0.3\) &\(0.3\) &\(29\) &\(29\) &\(72\) &\(72\)\\
    \(8.406\) & \(0.4\)&\(0.4\) & \(33\)&\(29\) & \(107\)&\(89\)\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Some comments and suggestions:

- If you use the line-drawing commands of the `booktabs` package to generate well-spaced horizontal rules, you shouldn't be using vertical rules.
- Use `\cmidrule` directives to provide more visual grouping for the header cells.
- Use the `\si` macro of the `siunitx` package to typeset well-formatted scientific units.
- For table with (mostly) numerical data, use the `S` column type (also by the `siunitx` package) instead of the basic `c` column type.
- There doesn't seem to be any need for line breaks in the header cells.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}
\newcommand{\mc}[1]{\multicolumn{2}{@{}c@{}}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!h]
\sisetup{table-format=3.0} % default
\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{@{}c *{2}{S[table-format=1.1]} *{4}{S} @{}}
    \toprule
    \(J\) 
    & \mc{Sovraelongazione} & \mc{Tempo di salita} & \mc{Tempo di assestamento} \\
    (\si{\kilogram\meter\squared}) & \mc{(\%)} & \mc{(msec)} & \mc{(msec)} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5} \cmidrule(l){6-7} 
    & \(PI-\mathit{diff}_{\omega_{\mathrm{bv}},J_{\mathrm{var}}}\)
    & \(PI-\mathit{diff}_{\omega_{\mathrm{bv}},J_{\mathrm{mid}}}\)
    & \(PI-\mathit{diff}_{\omega_{\mathrm{bv}},J_{\mathrm{var}}}\)
    & \(PI-\mathit{diff}_{\omega_{\mathrm{bv}},J_{\mathrm{mid}}}\)
    & \(PI-\mathit{diff}_{\omega_{\mathrm{bv}},J_{\mathrm{var}}}\)
    & \(PI-\mathit{diff}_{\omega_{\mathrm{bv}},J_{\mathrm{mid}}}\)\\
    \midrule
    0.225 & 0   & 0   & 27 & 28 &  69 & 71\\
    1.390 & 0.3 & 0.3 & 29 & 29 &  72 & 72\\
    8.406 & 0.4 & 0.4 & 33 & 29 & 107 & 89\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```